# How do I get Composer command arguments for custom scripts?

Tags: php, composer-php

My goal is to change the current user directory after a project has been created.

I am running `composer create-project vendor/repo some-directory`, and I have the following section, in the composer.json file.

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "cd /some/destination"
        ]
    }
}
```

So I need dynamically replace /some/destination with some-directory, specified in the command line arguments.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Composer does when you run `composer create-project vendor/repo some-directory` is (simplifying):

- Create the *some-directory* directory (If the directory is not empty, Composer raises the exception *Project directory some-directory/ is not empty.*)
- Change the current directory to *some-directory*
- Execute the scripts reported in the *scripts* section of the project composer.json file (In your case the one used from vendor/repo.)

So, if you are showing the *scripts* section used from the *vendor/repo*, changing the current directory to the directory where the project is being created is not necessary, since Composer already does that.
If you need to get the current directory from a Bash script listed in the *scripts* section of the project being created, you just check the content of the variable `$PWD`, which is the equivalent of `getcwd()` in PHP.

As example of what done from a Composer project, see the content of [ScriptHandler.php](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project/blob/8.x/scripts/composer/ScriptHandler.php), used from the Composer project [drupal-composer/drupal-project](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project). It creates some files in the directory whose filename is returned from `getcwd()`.

```
$fs = new Filesystem();
$drupalFinder = new DrupalFinder();
$drupalFinder->locateRoot(getcwd());
$drupalRoot = $drupalFinder->getDrupalRoot();
$dirs = [
  'modules',
  'profiles',
  'themes',
];
// Required for unit testing
foreach ($dirs as $dir) {
  if (!$fs->exists($drupalRoot . '/'. $dir)) {
    $fs->mkdir($drupalRoot . '/'. $dir);
    $fs->touch($drupalRoot . '/'. $dir . '/.gitkeep');
  }
}
```

Actually, it is creating the directories inside a directory found inside the current directory, but this doesn't change that the directory where the project is created is set as current directory from Composer.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#what-is-a-script-) :

> #### What is a script?
>
> A script, in Composer's terms, can either be a PHP
>   callback (defined as a static method) or any command-line executable
>   command.

so , you may either use a command like `mv` -*type `man mv` in your terminal for more info*- :

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "mv /some/destination /some-directory",
            "cd /some-directory"
        ]
    }
}
```

or by creating a callable method to handle this for you.

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "SomeVendor\\SomeObject::renameMyDirMethod"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: "some-directory" can be everything. It's a user input. I need to know the directory where the project actually is

Comment: @ymakux this is a pretty old comment, but I think that until now there are no feature to do though , https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2135#issuecomment-21930326

Comment: however, I don't know exactly what do you achieve here, by default `some-directory` is a user input, so whatever he will type composer will treat it as a user input

Comment: I have a script in the package, it allows users to do full step-by-step installation (e.g enter name, email, database details etc). So I want to "redirect" them to  that script to allow execute simple "php script install" command without worrying about where that script is located. It's like installation for housewives

Comment: Great, but I think that sometime you will have to restrict your users to do some specific steps, it is not a shame btw :)